# multiplicities of flat pullbacks

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes, divisors-algebraic-geometry

Let $f:X\to Y$ be a **flat morphism** between two Noetherian, integral, regular schemes. Let $D\in \operatorname{Div}(Y)$ any (Weil or Cartier) divisor, in this setting it has sense to consider the pullback $\,f^\ast D\in\operatorname{Div }(X)$.

Define the ramification index of $f$ at $x$ as:
$$e_x:=\operatorname{length}_{\mathcal O_{X,x}}\frac{\mathcal O_{X,x}}{\mathfrak m_{f(x)}\mathcal O_{X,x}}$$

I'd like to show that the following formula is true:

> $$f^\ast D=\sum_{x\in\star} e_x\operatorname{mult}_{f(x)}(D)\overline{\{x\}}$$
>   where $\star$ is the set of points $x\in X$ of codimension $1$ such that also $f(x)$ has codimension $1$. This formula is very important indeed it gives an explicit way to calculate the pullback of a divisor.

Can you give an hint for the proof or give any references? For instance the Stack project reference given [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/394634/degree-of-a-cartier-divisor-under-pullback) is wrong (probably the document has been updated).

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: The correct reference in the cited Stack-project document is 51.13, so maybe it was a typo.

Comment: Ok, it seems reasonable. But how can I use it?

Comment: I am just writing up an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\require{AMScd}$
$\newcommand{\spec}[1]{\mathrm{Spec}(#1)}$
$\newcommand{\tensor}{\otimes}$
$\newcommand{\ideal}[1]{\mathfrak{#1}}$

Let $f^*D$ be the left side of the equation and $f^\sharp D$ the right side of the equation. Then we note first that both sides are linear in $D$.

Consider the square
$$
\begin{CD}
X @<j'<< X' \\
@VVfV     @VVf'V \\
Y @<j<< Y'
\end{CD}
$$
where $j:Y' \to Y$ and $j':X' \to X$ are open immersions, and $f' = f|_{X'}$.

We assume, that $f'^*D = f'^\sharp D$ and we note

$$j'^\sharp f^\sharp D = f'^\sharp j^\sharp D$$

and

$$
\begin{align}
j^* D = j^\sharp D \\
j'^* E = j'^\sharp E
\end{align}
$$ 
for all divisors $D$ on $Y$ and $E$ on $X$.

Then
$$
\begin{equation}
j'^* f^* D = f'^* j^*D = f'^\sharp j^*D = f'^\sharp j^\sharp D = j'^\sharp f^\sharp D = j'^* f^\sharp D
\end{equation}
$$
As $X'$ and $Y'$ can vary over a cover of $f:X \to Y$ we have $f^*D = f^\sharp D$ provided this holds for every $f':X' \to Y'$ where $X'=\spec{B}$ and $Y'=\spec{A}$ are open affine subschemes of $X$ and $Y$.

So we can assume that $X=\spec{B}$, $Y=\spec{A}$ and (because of linearity and locality) that $D=(a)$ where $a$ is a nonzerodivisor of $A$.
Then $f^*D = (a)$ where $a$ is considered as element of $B$. It is a non-zero-divisor because $ -\tensor_A B$ is exact on $0 \to A \xrightarrow{\cdot a} A$.

Now choose a minimal prime $\ideal{q} \supseteq aB$, so that $\ideal{p} = \ideal{q} \cap A \supseteq (a)$ is a minimal prime over $aA$ (this follows from the going down property of the flat $B/A$).

The equation to be proved then reduces to the form

$$
\mathrm{len} B_\ideal{q}/a B_\ideal{q} = \mathrm{len} (B_\ideal{q}/\ideal{p} B_\ideal{q}) \mathrm{len} (A_\ideal{p}/a A_\ideal{p}) 
$$

But this follows from the cited Stacks 51.13 with $A = A_\ideal{p}$, $B = B_\ideal{q}$ and $M = A/aA$.